# Is there a way to validate by content that the file I am uploading is a .msg file?

Tags: outlook, file-format, msg

I need to validate that the file I am uploading is a .msg file. I want to do that by content. Because it is a Microsoft file, the header will be the same as `.doc` and `.xls` `(D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1)`. The only way to differentiate between the Microsoft formats is by subheader.

I have currently tried to validate against the subheader :

```
[512 (0x200) byte offset]
52 00 6F 00 6F 00 74 00
20 00 45 00 6E 00 74 00
72 00 79 00)
```

It worked on sample files, but when I save an Outlook mail (`.msg`) and try to validate, it does not have that subheader (the one above). I currently have `Outlook 2010`. Does someone know why it does not contain the subheader? or what alternative should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSG file (just like the old DOC and XLS formats) is an OLE storage file. You can check if the "__properties_version1.0" stream exists - take a look an an MSG file with a viewer like [SSView](https://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [MSG file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) is described in depth.